# How is the screen resolution calculated for phones with curved edges and rounded corners?

Tags: screen, screen-resolution

Consider phones like the pixel 2, Samsung or iPhone X with notches and non rectangular screens. How is the screen resolution calculated? Do they take a rectangular screen with a standard resolution and 'chop off the edges' and use the regular value as the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I asked ##techsupport on freenode and they answered it. If anyone else is looking for the answer:
The resolution specifies a rectangular screen with the same width and height of the screen. Rounded edges and notches are the rectangular screen with the appropriate bits cut out